# C# WMI Remote Process Create -GUI Hack

Tags: c#, wmi

I've written a C# Windows Service that restarts processes and services on remote machines.

It works fine, however for some of the processes that I need to restart, The application needs a GUI....

.....Are there any hacks to get the GUI to display when starting a process remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the application has any parameters it can take to suppress the GUI and just pass it along. I know we suppress [BGInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx)'s prompt using `/accepteula` on some of our VMs.